# How do I automatically display data by current week and last week?

Tags: php, sql

I have a this weeks current totals, from monday to monday and Last weeks totals. I have been manually updating the timestamps to reflect the current and last week. I would like have it just pull the data from the current week from monday to monday and last weeks from monday to monday

This weeks code.

```
echo "This Week&nbsp;<br />";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2011-11-7' AND '2011-11-14' AND checkcollec = 'yes'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<b>Checks Collected:</b> $num_rows &nbsp;";
```

Last weeks Code.

```
echo "<hr />Last Week&nbsp;<br />";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2011-10-31' AND '2011-11-07' AND checkcollec = 'yes'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<b>Checks Collected:</b> $num_rows &nbsp;";
```

How can I do this so I do not have to keep changing it manually each week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$todayMinusSeven = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-7 days"));

$query = "SELECT * FROM form2 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$todayMinusSeven' AND 
    '$today' AND checkcollec = 'yes'";

echo $query;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the SQL-Part to

```
SELECT * 
FROM form_2 
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -7 DAY) 
    AND checkcollec = 'yes';
```

If `NOW()` is not the date-variable you need, just substitute it with a variable of your needs, p.e. while setting it in your php script somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

All other soltions do give the results for the last 7 days, as I understand you want the week from monday to monday and the week before that.
Depending on which sql server you have, you can use a week() function like

```
WHERE week(timestamp) = week(NOW())
```

The syntax may be different and maybe you need to set a second parameter for week so that it starts with monday.

Comment: MySQL client version: 5.1.56 also How would I display last?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week so you could use week(NOW(),1). For last week you could just use a timestamp from the last week or one of the methods from the other answers like DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -7 DAY)

Comment: No, my solution is Monday to Monday, and works for MySQL. Figured he's using MySQL from the `mysql_query()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This week:

```
SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN curdate() - weekday(curdate()) AND curdate() - weekday(curdate()) + 7 AND checkcollec = 'yes'
```

Last week:

```
SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN curdate() - weekday(curdate()) - 7 AND curdate() - weekday(curdate()) AND checkcollec = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about showing data in current week. TS said that data show from monday to monday and last weeks from monday to monday. in my suggest, we can use WEEKOFYEAR function to get data in a week.

This Week:

```
SELECT * 
FROM form_2 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)=WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND checkcollec = 'yes'
```

Last Week:

```
SELECT *
FROM form_2 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)=WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())-1  
    AND checkcollec = 'yes'
```